# Body background doesn't match up with main content background

Tags: bug, design, winterbash

If you're on [the main site](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/), you can see a visible line around the site where the main content background doesn't match up with the tiled background used as the background image for the body. This is only noticable once your browser window exceeds a width of 1560px (the size of the container background) or if you scroll down.

[image]

It's more noticeable on the actual site as opposed to the screenshot above. :(

- Body background: http://cdn.sstatic.net/gaming/img/hatdash-snowtile.jpg
- Content div background: http://cdn.sstatic.net/gaming/img/hatdash-bg.jpg?v=2

Once you see it, you can't unsee it. :(

Please save the pixels from this horrible fate... you know, if you have bandwidth in your image manipulation department. <3

-1 if your response is that my pixels are in another castle/webpage.

+1 if you make <3 or [<3] render the GSE heart (feature creep!).

Comment: I can only see it on the bottom, so it's pretty negligible unless I zoom out...would you happen to be doing that? Because the hatdash background is 1560 pixels wide.

Comment: @Ullallulloo nope, HD screens.

Comment: @alexanderpas: okay, but it's still more than 1104px.

Comment: My resolution is 1920x1080. You're right on the image size being 1560px, I messed up and gave you the size Firefox shows when it decides to be "helpful" and reduce the image size so you can see it all. Question edited!

Comment: liek dis if you crei evry tiem